# How to detect chrome 53 blocking flash?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash

It seems that since Chrome updated to v53, it started blocking Flash content, displaying a little notification at the right of the url.

I read that "Chrome 53 puts an end to the use of Flash in the background for page analytics." and that it will shift toward Html5 in december 2016.

My question is : Is there a way of detecting Flash being blocked by Chrome 53+?

Until now my solution was to check Flash being installed or not on Chrome but it's not working anymore.

Thank you.

Comment: `it started blocking Flash content` I did not know that (I don't use Chrome as my primary browser). I think that's awesome. Everything to hasten Flash's demise. But regarding your question - is there a particular reason you need to know that? Most websites either don't care (content just doesn't show - browser manages notification for that) or, say, put a background image that will be covered up by the Flash content if its loaded. Source: I've been browsing without Flash enabled for 3-4 years now, and that's what I've seen.

Comment: For work purpose I'm currently more or less stuck with using Flash at the moment. As a short-term solution I need a way to detect this blockage before being able to replace Flash completely.